# Cross-Platform Vector Format

Tags: svg, cross-platform, vector-graphics

Does there exist a data (file?) format representing a resizable vector graphic that can be exported to iOS CoreGraphics AND be rendered on a Linux server? I've been considering SVG with [this library](https://github.com/SVGKit/SVGKit), but I need support for text and element constraints (i.e. pinning elements to edges).

Comment: You might want to test the SVGgh library.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of a file format that provides the functionality that you are looking for out of the box.

But you may want to consider using SVG in combination with [Paper.js](http://paperjs.org). In Paper.js you can add custom data to any item (http://paperjs.org/reference/item/#data). Using Javascript you can then interpret the data and use it for applying your constraints prior to rendering.

Please note that while Paper.js is quite good for doing layout of elements (applying your constraints should be easy) and it has SVG import and export, but it does not support the full SVG spec (especially filters are missing).